# Removing lines from a CSV

Tags: parsing, powershell, csv

I have a csv document with multiple headers like:

```
"Date","RQ","PM","SME","Activity","Status code"
"2/2/12","6886","D_WV","John Smith","Recent","2004"
```

and a text document that is just a list of status codes, one per line.

I am trying to figure out how to remove all lines from the CSV that contain the status codes from the text file.

So far I have tried using:

```
$m = gc textfile.txt
Select-String data.csv -Pattern $m -NotMatch
```

However that leaves me with extra data such as

```
data.csv:1"Date","RQ","PM","SME","Activity","Status code"
data.csv:2"2/2/12","6886","D_WV","John Smith","Recent","2004"
```

I have also tried:

```
gc data.csv | ? { $_ -notlike $m }
```

That uses the proper formatting but does not want to remove any of the values. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those matchinfo objects from select-string can be confusing.
 Does this do what you need?

```
$m = gc textfile.txt
select-string data.csv -pattern $m -notmatch |
select -expand line
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I did not know about expand line. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach to avoid false positives:

```
$m = Get-Content textfile.txt
Import-Csv data.csv `
  | ? { $m -notcontains $_."Status code" } `
  | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```