# Powershell csv remove lines

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file (`file1`) that looks like: (User dirs and the size)

```
Initials,Size    
User1,10    
User2,100    
User3,131
User4,140
```

I have another CSV file (`file2`) that looks like: (VIP users)

```
User2    
User4
```

Now what I'm trying to do, is to update `file1`, so it looks like:

```
User1,10    
User3,131
```

`User2` and `User4` is removed because they are in `file2`

I can get them removed, but at the same time I remove the size for all users, so my output is only the Users:

```
User1    
User3
```

My code:

```
$SourcePath = "\\server1\info\SYSINFO\UsrSize"    
$DestinationFile = "\\server1\info\SYSINFO\UsrSize\OverLimit\UsersOverLimit1.log"    
$VIP_Exclusion_List = "\\server1\info\SYSINFO\UsrSize\OverLimit\_VIP_EXCLUSION_LIST.txt"    
$Database = "\\server1\info\SYSINFO\UsrSize\OverLimit\_UsersOverLimitDATABASE.log"    
$INT_SizeToLookFor = 100    

dir $SourcePath -Filter usr*.txt | import-csv -delimiter "`t"  | 
Where-Object {[INT] $_."Size excl. Backup/Pst" -ge $INT_SizeToLookFor} |
Select-Object Initials,"Size excl. Backup/Pst" | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file  $DestinationFile   ;

$Userlist = import-csv $DestinationFile | Select-Object Initials | 
convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""};

compare-object ($Userlist) (get-content $VIP_Exclusion_List) |
select-object inputObject | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation |
% { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file "\\server1\info\SYSINFO\UsrSize\OverLimit\UsersOverLimitThisTime.log";
```

Comment: Found part of the answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579316/removing-lines-from-a-csv-with-powershell?rq=1

Now I just need to find a way to export it to a CSV file again

Comment: out-file works fine :-) Will add the full new code, when the site allows me to.

Comment: export-csv is the Cmd-Let to create a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this code:

$ArrayVIP = get-content $VIP_Exclusion_List 
select-string $DestinationFile -pattern $ArrayVIP -notmatch | 
select -expand line | 
out-file $DestinationFile

Taken from here: [Removing lines from a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579316/removing-lines-from-a-csv-with-powershell?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If the files are small-ish and you don't care too much about performance, then the following would be a trivial way:

```
$data = Import-Csv file1
$vips = Import-Csv file2
$data = $data | ?{ $vips -notcontains $_.Initials }
$data | Export-Csv file1_new -NoTypeInformation
```

A faster way would be to add the names to remove to a set, but given the things you're talking about here I doubt you'll get into the range of a few thousand or million users.